# How shall I read out data from a binary Excel from node.js REST API file and display it in HTML using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, excel

I'm getting binary excel(.xls) data from node.js REST API, now I need to consume this service in Angular controller and convert this binary excel(.xls) file and preview the Excel in my project directly without downloading.

My code is

```
$scope.exportToExcel = function () {
    function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
        contentType = contentType || '';
        sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

        var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
        var byteArrays = [];

        for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
            var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

            var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

            byteArrays.push(byteArray);
        }

        var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });

        return blob;
    }

    var contentType = 'binary/octet-stream';
    var b64Data = data;

    var convert = b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType);
    // var blob = URL.createObjectURL(convert);
    console.log("DOWNLOAD: " + URL.createObjectURL(convert))
    saveAs(convert, "Report.xls");
}
```

On Click action this code runs and download the binary data as excel file, but instead of downloading I need to directly display it in browser, I'm using Angularjs

Please guide me in this. Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Comment: @ Fabian Schöner, I edited the question with code. Please check